# Usage of verb abound

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, adjectives

I have certain confusions regarding the Verb Abound. Abound is a verb which means to exist in large numbers or amounts. What we generally understand from a Verb is Action. However the Verb abound seems like an aberration where it is depicting a condition or situation.                                Why is this the case? Why we need such Verbs in English Language when we can simply use Adjectives like abundant?

Comment: @We oath to creation..It happened by mistake. It was a deleted question. I have changed my question. Please Check.

Comment: You just used 'have', 'is', 'means', 'exist', understand', 'seems' and 'need'. I suggest you try writing your question _without_ using any 'non-action' verbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Abound` is a verb, even if it isn't *doing* what we might consider an "action". A good similar verb would be **[exist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exist)**.

`Abound` really isn't used that frequently though. I (incorrectly) thought it had a negative tone to it as I've only used it ways such as:

*Defects and glitches abound in Billy's project that is already too expensive.*

Note `abound` could be replaced with other verbs such as:

- Accumulate
- Exist
- Grow

However, apparently `abound` can be a positive/neutral as well:

*Praise and glory abound in PGSystemTester's project that came in under budget.*

Again `abound` could be replaced with:

- Amass
- Acccumulate
- Exist

Hope that helps.

Comment: Tester... Thanks for a great answer. Can you please upvote my question. It will help to get the question ban lifted from my account.